# Angular momentum conservation in the 2HDM

Tags: particle-physics, angular-momentum, standard-model, higgs, beyond-the-standard-model

One of the experimentally searched decay chains of the 2HDM is the decay of a pseudoscalar Higgs boson A into the SM one and a Z boson. I was wondering how (from a very naive point of view) this works with angular momentum conservation. The A has spin 0, the Higgs has spin 0 and the Z has spin 1. Aren't you creating angular momentum out of nowhere here? Is it because the observable Z field is a mixture of B_mu and W_3?

Any suggenstions are more than welcome :) Thanks a lot already

Comment: Consider to spell out acronyms.

Comment: Oh yeah - I apologize for that. Althoug I think it does not matter that much here. 2HDM is Two-Higgs-Doublet-Model, SM is Standard Model, B_mu and W_3 are the fields of U(1)_Y and SU(2)_L before spontaneous symmetry breaking

Answer (score 0):

In this paper, [for super symmetric](https://arxiv.org/pdf/hep-ph/9511342.pdf) higgses,  there is formula 15, where

A -> Z* h -> h f f_bar

i.e. the Z and h are off mass shell, the real particles being three, and angular momentum can be conserved. This presupposes that the mass of A is smaller than the mass of Z, so it is context dependent, i.e. where you found the decay discussed.

Otherwise I have the same problem for a real two body decay Z h . At the center of mass, as they are point particles they can only decay back to back, and not take any angular momentum to compensate for the intrinsic spin of the Z. Maybe a theoretician can look at it.